# css toggle switch + loading state

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I'm trying to make a toogle switch with pure css. I've got it working so far, but I would like to add a third state "pending" beeing a middle state between "on" and "off" (Usually, there is a delay of data processing when toggling on/off). So I would like to have a spinner on the white circle in that 'pending'state.

I've tried many things but got nothing satisfying so far.

Here is the basic code with only two state. How can I modify it do to what i want? Thanks.

```js
function ToogleStateCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.plugin = {
    enabled: false
  }

  $scope.toggleState = function() {
    console.log('toggling from ' + $scope.plugin.enabled + ' to ' + !$scope.plugin.enabled);
    $scope.plugin.pending = true;
    //delay to simulate pending state
    setTimeout(doToggle, 2000);
  }

  function doToggle() {
    console.log('do toggling')
    $scope.plugin.pending = false;
    $scope.plugin.enabled = !$scope.plugin.enabled;
    $scope.$apply()
  }
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 22px;
}

.switch-slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.switch-slider.enabled {
  border-color: green;
  background-color: green;
}

.switch-slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.switch-slider.enabled:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ToogleStateCtrl">
    <div id="srv-state" class="switch vertical-center" ng-click="toggleState()">
      <div class="switch-slider" ng-class="{'disabled' : !plugin.enabled , 'enabled': plugin.enabled, 'pending': plugin.pending, 'loaded': !plugin.pending}"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to change the color of the control, put your appropriate animation in class loading.

```js
function ToogleStateCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.plugin = {
    enabled: false
  }

  $scope.toggleState = function() {
    console.log('toggling from ' + $scope.plugin.enabled + ' to ' + !$scope.plugin.enabled);
    $scope.plugin.pending = true;
    //delay to simulate pending state
    $scope.change='loading';
    setTimeout(doToggle, 2000);
  }

  function doToggle() {
    console.log('do toggling')
    $scope.plugin.pending = false;
    $scope.plugin.enabled = !$scope.plugin.enabled;
    $scope.change='loading_completed';
    $scope.$apply()
  }
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 22px;
}

.switch-slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.switch-slider.enabled {
  border-color: green;
  background-color: green;
}

.switch-slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.loading:before
{
 background-color: blue;
}

.loading_completed:before
{
 background-color: white;
}

.switch-slider.enabled:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ToogleStateCtrl">
    <div id="srv-state" class="switch vertical-center" ng-click="toggleState()">
      <div class="switch-slider {{change}}" ng-class="{'disabled' : !plugin.enabled , 'enabled': plugin.enabled, 'pending': plugin.pending, 'loaded': !plugin.pending}"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well that is actually the issue here... adding an animation. Let's say I want that to spin untill loading_completed. How to do? (see my comment below for a trial that doesn't work :/)

Answer (score 0):

@Sumangal Well that is actually the issue here... adding an animation.
Let's say I want that to spin untill loading_completed. How to do?

Here is what I tried: added a keyframe and use 'animation' css pros, but got unwanted behaviour! :/

```js
function ToogleStateCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.plugin = {
    enabled: false
  }

  $scope.toggleState = function() {
    console.log('toggling from ' + $scope.plugin.enabled + ' to ' + !$scope.plugin.enabled);
    $scope.plugin.pending = true;
    //delay to simulate pending state
    $scope.change='loading';
    setTimeout(doToggle, 2000);
  }

  function doToggle() {
    console.log('do toggling')
    $scope.plugin.pending = false;
    $scope.plugin.enabled = !$scope.plugin.enabled;
    $scope.change='loading_completed';
    $scope.$apply()
  }
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 22px;
}

.switch-slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.switch-slider.enabled {
  border-color: green;
  background-color: green;
}

.switch-slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.loading:before
{
 border-style: dashed;
 animation: spin 2s infinite linear
}

.loading_completed:before
{
 background-color: white;
}

.switch-slider.enabled:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);

  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ToogleStateCtrl">
    <div id="srv-state" class="switch vertical-center" ng-click="toggleState()">
      <div class="switch-slider {{change}}" ng-class="{'disabled' : !plugin.enabled , 'enabled': plugin.enabled, 'pending': plugin.pending, 'loaded': !plugin.pending}"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```